# what will happen if two threads are joined in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Say i have two threads t1 and t2, as per Oracle docs, t1.join means the current thread will wait for t1 to finish.My question is, what if the threads have already finished ? eg:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new EventThread("e1"));
t1.start();
Thread e2 = new Thread(new EventThread("e2"));
t2.start();
while (true)
{
    try {
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    break;
    }
}
```

What if t2 is already finished ?

Comment: What are the options? Have you done any testing? Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long))?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [`join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()):

> An invocation of this method behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation
>
> ```
> join(0)
> ```

And the documentation of [`join(long millis)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long)) says:

> This implementation uses a loop of `this.wait` calls **conditioned on `this.isAlive`**.

So if `isAlive` returns `false` (i.e. the thread finished), the `wait` is never called and `join` just returns immediately.